# Is it possible to get the owner for a Google Drive file?

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

When I look at my Google Drive online, I see files have the owner listed, sometimes shown as  "Shared By" myself or someone else.  Is it possible to obtain this value programmatic-ally (using C#)?

Ideally I want to have someone share a file with me, then me do some processing on the file (via a Windows Service), and then me re-upload the file with it's alterations.  I would need to know the owner of the file though.

Is this possible? Is this possible without using the Google Drive API?  - I'm thinking about using normal .NET/Windows functions to pull the file out of the Google Drive local folder...

Comment: If you want to do this I highly suggest just using the Google Drive API.  You wouldn't be able to poll information the Google Drive's information unless you did.

Comment: That makes sense. I didn't know if Google added some unseen metadata to the files that I could obtain without the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File resources returned by the Google Drive API include a `userPermission` field which lists users authorized to access the document together with their role (owner, reader or writer):

https://developers.google.com/drive/v1/reference/files#resource

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar need. I am thinking of developing an application to process the files shared by users and display them some reports. So, my application needs to uniquely identify the owner so that only he and none other can view the reports for his files.

Looking at the answer given above by Claudio, I debugged in Java to examine the "userPermission" field, but could not find anything of help. I also examined other fields of the file, but got nothing except the name of the owner in string format.

Is there a way it can be achieved? Would need some help. Thank you.