# Delete old files from a Google Drive folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I created this script to delete files published more than 3 hours ago. And even if the latest file is older than 3 hours, it will not be deleted, so the folder will never be empty.

I enabled google's advanced service called DRIVE API V2.

I activated a trigger to analyze the folder every 5 minutes, but often the files are not deleted, they remain in the folder. The script works sometimes yes and sometimes no.

**I would like to know what is wrong or what I need to edit to make it work perfectly.**

```
function getOldFileIDs() {
  // Old date is 3 Hours
  var oldDate = new Date().getTime() - 3600*1000*3;
  var cutOffDate = new Date(oldDate).toISOString();

  // Get folderID using the URL on google drive
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
  var files = folder.searchFiles('modifiedDate < "' + cutOffDate + '"');

  var obj = [];
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    obj.push({id: file.getId(), date: file.getDateCreated()});
  }
  obj.sort(function(x, y) {return x.date < y.date ? 1 : -1});
  obj.shift();
  var fileIDs = obj.map(function(e) {return e.id});
  return fileIDs;
};

function deleteFiles() {
  var fileIDs = getOldFileIDs();
  fileIDs.forEach(function(fileID) {
    Drive.Files.remove(fileID);
  });
};
```

**I also want some help so that this script can analyze if there are files with the same name inside the folder, if it exists, it delete surplus ones so that there is always only one file with each name.**

And new detail, a new error appeared that until earlier did not happen ... Saying that:

API call failed for drive.files.delete with error Insufficient permissions for this file (line 24)

Line 24:

```
    Drive.Files.remove(fileID);
```

Comment: related [Delete files via Drive API failed with error: Insufficient permissions for this file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55150681/1595451)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using consumer (free) accounts, only the file owner is able to delete them. To prevent the error, before calling `Drive.Files.remove(fileID)` your code should check if you are the file owner.

Related

- [Is it possible to get the owner for a Google Drive file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11142988/1595451)
- [How to get the owner of file using Google Drive API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11304767/1595451)
- [How to programmticly remove a file from "share wtih me" in Google drive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56770881/1595451)
- [How to retrieve the owner or Drive ID of a document with Google APIs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57087672/1595451)

Comment: Thank you very much for your attention ... I've been looking at the links you sent me, but unfortunately I won't be able to reproduce what is required for both accounts to have full access to all files in the folder. My programming knowledge is very limited. But I will try to hire someone to do this service for me, I really can't do it myself. I hope it is not an expensive service.

Comment: I added two more links.

Comment: @FredericoMattos Another alternative is to tweak the following line to include only files owned by you `var files = folder.searchFiles('modifiedDate < "' + cutOffDate + '"');`

Comment: `var files = folder.searchFiles('modifiedDate < "' + cutOffDate + '" and "me@gmail.com" in owners ');` Would it be this way Rubén?

Comment: I suggest you to create an account for testing purposes and try the above codeline

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 obj.sort(function(a, b) {
    var a=new Date(a.date).valueOf();
    var b=new Date(b.date).valueOf();
    return b-a;
  });
```

Comment: Cooper, I updated the question, a new error appeared now ... I put in the end the error that is appearing, could you help me please?

Comment: Did you enabled the API on the Google Cloud API Console? Also is this a file that you own?It looks like you don't have permission to delete this file.

Comment: I also tested with the account that created the folder. But it still gives the same error. I enabled Google Drive API V2 on Google's advanced service

Until today at 15 hours everything was working perfectly, now I realized that has stopped completely and is giving this error. And I didn't change anything.