# Google Drive - App Scripts - How to delete a file from the trash

Tags: google-drive-api

I am writing a google drive apps script to poll my google trash (using the DriveApp.getTrashedFiles method).

However, although this correctly lists the files, I can find no way to actually delete the file.

I want to be able to delete files every hour or day using a trigger and not have to rely on the 30-day file deletion method, as I find my drive fills up before then.

Can anyone advise how I can use App Scripts to delete a file I've identified in the trash or to simply empty the trash? It used to be supported but seems it's changed !!

Thanks

Comment: Is this thread useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/q/58228969/7108653

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete old files from a Google Drive folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58228969/delete-old-files-from-a-google-drive-folder)